# Why is my Mac Terminal using Chinese double quotes?

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, chinese

I am trying to type `cd ~/` in my terminal, and I got

```
cd: no such file or directory: “/Users/xiwei”/
```

For some reason, it's using the Chinese Quote “” instead of the standard  "".

If I type `cd "/Users/xiwei"`, it works. If I type `cd “/Users/xiwei”`, it's the same error.

This is a new MacBook Pro I brought in China, but the `Region` in setting is `United States` and the `Preferred language` is `English`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was a mistake I made in my `.zshrc`. I had export `HOME=“/Users/xiwei”`. Smart Quote was applied when I copy/paste.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what makes them 'Chinese'. They're Smart Quotes.
Terminal shouldn't use smart quotes unless you are copy/pasting from another text document that does.

There's an overall pref in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text to enable or disable them, but individual apps such as TextEdit can override that on a per document basis, so if the overall system pref is off check the menu in your text app…

[image]

TextEdit menu

[image]